# iis log analysis related inquiries

Tags: iis

When the client sends data to iis through the api, iis stores it in the db and sends the response data back to the client.

It seems that the client is taking a long time to receive the response data

So, I am trying to analyze the iis log, but the iis log file is saved like this

```
2022-10-27 00:08:51 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx POST /Update - 2038 - xx.xxx.xx.xxx Java/1.8.0_202 - 200 0 0 855
2022-10-27 00:15:32 xxx.xxx.xx.xxx POST /Update - 2038 - xx.xxx.xx.xxx Java/1.8.0_202 - 200 0 0 12
```

I know that the last data is time-taken, but I am confused whether it refers to the time-taken response speed or the time received by the client. How should I analyze the log?

The client says it takes more than 8 seconds to receive the response data. I want to know if there is anything I need to change the iis setting

Comment: Microsoft accurately documented the meaning of `time-taken` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/health-diagnostic-performance/time-taken-field-http-log You still have a lot to dig into, such as other network components on the wire, but that's not programming related.

Comment: Time-taken is the time it takes from when IIS receives the first byte in the request until it sends out the last byte in that request. The start time of when the first byte is received by IIS is the "time" field and the finish time when IIS sends out that the last byte is the "time" field + the "time-taken" field.